# Loading Data from SQL into R

Tags: sql, r, parallel-processing

I am using following code

```
ORT<-sqlQuery(channel, "Select ort FROM test")
ORT<-ORT[,c("ort")]
ORT<-as.list(ORT)
ORT <- parLapply(cl,ORT,function(ORT) cleanup(ORT))
sqlSave(channel, ORT,tablename="table_name1")
```

First I load a column of my Sql database into R, that works fine. Next thing is I want to run a function using the parallel package. Here comes the first problem, ORT needs to be a character vector but Sql imports the vector as a data frame. Is there any fast way to convert? Since the vector contains 10 millions entries.

Next problem is: How to save the data vector back to the database, my sqlSave command does not work!

Comment: Coerce to a vector before calling it from a db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `ORT<-ORT[,c("ort")]`, I suspect that R is allocating new memory and copying the contents of `ORT$ort`.  If you just keep the data frame and pass `ORT$ort` to `parLapply` then you can skip this step. (Also note that you don't need the `as.list` step.  `parLapply` accepts vectors.)

I'd be surprised if this was the slow part of your analysis.  Reading from and writing to databases usually takes much longer than allocating new vectors.

If you want the result as a vector in order to use with `sqlSave` then use `parSapply` instead of `parLapply`.